# Why its not recommended to pass object to fragment with simple getter setter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to android, I wonder why this easy method for parameter passing is not recommended.

```
class DemoFragment extends Fragment{
    private MyObject myObject;
    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObject){
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }
}

DemoFragment fragmentDemo = new DemoFragment();
fragmentDemo.setMyObject(myObject);
```

Comment: Who told you that?

Comment: Farhad don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: You can edit them, if you have better tags to add.

Comment: I dont think it's not recommended. For complex objects, how you can pass them to fragment without getters, setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism that Android provides for parameter passing to Fragments is using Bundles, which is the same technique in Activity to Activity data passing.

When creating your Fragment, call its `setArguments(Bundle bundle)` method with the desired key-values that you want.

Also another advantage is that you can persist this arguments during configuration changes in the device, like the orientation change.

Using getters and setters is not a bad practice generally, but you better take the most out of the native APIs before trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Why using Bundles instead of simple setters?

When you rotate the screen of the device (a.k.a. "orientation change" or " configuration change") the fragment `DemoFragment` is destroyed and then recreated by android. So the content of `DemoFragment.myObject` is lost after the rotation if supplied via the setter.

The non-intuitive "Bundle" info is *not* lost after screen rotation. When DemoFragment is re-created it receives the data from the bundle again so `DemoFragment.myObject` is filled again with the required parameter.

For more details see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

If it doesn-t matter that a class member get lost after "screen rotation" then setters are fine.