# Passing Objects to fragment without argument

Tags: android, object, android-fragments

What will be the implications if I passed an `object` to a `fragment` without using `bundle`? I just opened one of the old code and found it there and couldn't help asking this question as I have never tried it. Also I am not finding any memory leaks in it.

This is how it is implemented -

**Activity class:**

```
MyFragment fragment =
        MyFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getStringExtra(DATA),
            instance.getCallback(),
            instance.getRequest());
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

**Fragment class:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  public MyFragment() {
    /* Required empty public constructor */
  }

  public static MyFragment newInstance(String data, Callback callback,
      Request request) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setCallback(callback);
    fragment.setRequest(request);
    fragment.setData(data);
    return fragment;
  }

  private void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  private void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  private void setRequest(Request request) {
    this.request = request;
  }
}
```

Generally, what I have used till date is `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)`

Comment: If you use data external to your fragment, that is from a getter setter from a singleton class, then obviously the data will not be the property of the fragment. You also will have to struggle to wipe that data out from the memory.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean chances for memory leaks are there in this case. I failed to get any of those though. But even I suspected memory leaks will be there

Comment: Yes, that is why it is forbidden to have static pointers to any context based variables, like view, activity, so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out this answer: [Why its not recommended to pass object to fragment with simple getter setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129833/why-its-not-recommended-to-pass-object-to-fragment-with-simple-getter-setter).

Long story short, you will lose your data on configuration changes.

There are mainly two ways of communicating with a fragment: via bundles or via an interface that you implement in your activity. Please see this link in order to see how to properly communicate with a fragment via an interface: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating