# Statically added Fragment can't restore instance state?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

when i add a Fragment statically in the Activity layout, i can't seem to be able to recover the state in `onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle)` even though `onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)` is called correctly.

It works for the same Fragment, when i add it dynamically.

Is this simply not possible to do this or does it require additional configuration in the Manifest or w/e

**EDIT:** `onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle)` will be called, but the Bundle is null, as well as in other Lifecycle callbacks that pass the Bundle through

Comment: Post the src code

Answer (score -1):

You should post also the code where you add your fragment, not sure what you mean by statically add a fragment.

Please check out also this answers:

- [Passing Objects to fragment without argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669374/passing-objects-to-fragment-without-argument/53669702#53669702)
- [setArguments() in Fragment and onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652526/setarguments-in-fragment-and-oncreate/53652682#53652682)

If still don't figure it out, paste your code.